# Does RequireJS optimizer still work if define() is not a top-level function call?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, optimization

I want to write a universal JavaScript module that can be loaded by both node.js and RequireJS, so I would write something like this:

```
(function() {
  if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    // node.js 
    module.exports = ...;
  } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define([...], function(...) {
      return ...;
    });
  }
})();
```

Would RequireJS optimizer still work in this case?

Comment: Try it!  I'm curious to see what the answer is.

Answer (score 0):

Last time, when I try to make it work - requirejs did't see dependent files.

So I used "include" config parameter.